# Vue3: Bootstrap Modal Pass Param To Form

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, vuejs3

Pretty new to Vue3, I have been leveraging Bootstrap 4.6 in my Vue3 application. I need to pass a data param called redirect when clicking on the button to pass an anchor tag value so I can redirect once I have authenticated.

```
//Login modal

<script>
import jquery from "jquery";

export default {

data() {

    jquery(document).on("show.bs.modal", "#loginModal", function (e) {
      var param = e.relatedTarget;
      var rs = param.getAttribute("data-anchor");
      //I have tried this approach but can't get the form value to submit because I cannot write to the v-model??
      document.getElementById("redirect").value = rs;
      //I have also tried to update the data variable too.
      this.redirect = rs;
      //It does return the data-anchor value to the console but doesn't update the redirect var?
      console.log(rs);
    });

return {

   redirect: ''

}

}

</script>

//Button on parent page
 <a
    href="#"
    data-anchor="#anchor1"
    data-target="#loginModal"
    data-toggle="modal"
    type="button"
    >Login
 </a>
```